# Mixpanel: export all events instead of first 100,200

Tags: mixpanel

I am going to export a list of unique devices for app installation by selecting a single tracking and scroll to bottom until all sessions are loaded, page by page , 100 events per page.

Please tell me more convenient way to export all events  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways in which you can export your events from Mixpanel. If you were interested in the full event info then the Mixpanel [/export API](https://developer.mixpanel.com/reference/raw-data-export-api) or the [export_events()](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-utils#export-events) function in the Mixpanel-utils module would be probably be best.

If you wanted another method to do this from the UI and were only interested in some of the information from the events the Insights report could be more what you were looking for. There you can build a report with your app installation event and breakdown by the distinct_id to get a table of that information. The overflow icon in the top right will contain a download option where you can export a CSV of the info in the report. Do note that the CSV export is [limited to 10K unique rows](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004562723-Downloading-Reports-from-Mixpanel). Hope that helps!